# how do I pass the key to ng-class in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

How do I pass 'key' to the `activeClass(key)` method using AngularJs?

```
<li ng-class="activeClass(key)" ng-repeat="(key, data) in bigData">
    <label>{{data.label}}
        <input type="radio" name="market" value="{{key}}" ng-model="myModel">
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: the key is passed only see here http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/j8E2a/1/